# Alternative to arg_scope when using tf.layers

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-layers

I'm rewriting `tf.contrib.slim.nets.inception_v3` using `tf.layers`. Unfortunately the new `tf.layers` module does not work with `arg_scope`, as it does not have the necessary decorators. Is there better mechanism in place that I should use to set default paramters for layers? Or should I simply add a proper arguments to each layer and remove the `arg_scope`?

Here is an example that uses the arg_scope:

```
with variable_scope.variable_scope(scope, 'InceptionV3', [inputs]):
    with arg_scope(
        [layers.conv2d, layers_lib.max_pool2d, layers_lib.avg_pool2d],
        stride=1,
        padding='VALID'):
```

Comment: You should use the proper arguments for each layer. For initializers, you can use `variable_scope`'s `initializer` argument

Comment: @KathyWu can you put this as an answer with example so I can accept that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't another mechanism that lets you define default values in core TensorFlow, so you should specify the arguments for each layer.

For instance, this code:

```
with slim.arg_scope([slim.fully_connected], 
    activation_fn=tf.nn.relu, 
    weights_initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.01),
    weights_regularizer=tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(scale=0.0005)):
  x = slim.fully_connected(x, 800)
  x = slim.fully_connected(x, 1000)
```

would become:

```
x = tf.layers.dense(x, 800, activation=tf.nn.relu,
      kernel_initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.01),
      kernel_regularizer=tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(scale=0.0005))
x = tf.layers.dense(x, 1000, activation=tf.nn.relu,
      kernel_initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.01),
      kernel_regularizer=tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(scale=0.0005))
```

Alternatively:

```
with tf.variable_scope('fc', 
    initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.01)):
  x = tf.layers.dense(x, 800, activation=tf.nn.relu,
      kernel_regularizer=tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(scale=0.0005))
  x = tf.layers.dense(x, 1000, activation=tf.nn.relu,
      kernel_regularizer=tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(scale=0.0005))
```

Make sure to read the documentation of the layer to see which initializers default to the variable scope initializer. For example, the [dense layer](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/dense)'s `kernel_initializer` uses the variable scope initializer, while the `bias_initializer` uses `tf.zeros_initializer()`.

Answer (score 2):

you can use [add_arg_scope](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/framework/add_arg_scope) from **tensorflow.contrib.framework** which adds the necessary decorators and makes a function usable with **arg_scope**. Create a wrapper around tf.layers.**requiredLayer** and decorate it with @add_arg_scope.

Example :

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.contrib.framework import arg_scope
from tensorflow.contrib.framework import add_arg_scope

@add_arg_scope
def conv2d(inputs,filters,kernel_size,padding='VALID',activation=tf.nn.sigmoid):
    print inputs
    print filters
    print kernel_size
    print padding
    print activation
    return tf.layers.conv2d(
                  inputs=inputs,
                  filters=filters,
                  kernel_size=kernel_size,
                  padding=padding,
                  activation=activation)

inp = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,224,224,3])


print '--------net1-------------'
with arg_scope([conv2d],padding='SAME',activation=tf.nn.relu):
    net = conv2d(inputs=inp,filters=64,kernel_size=[1,1])
    #print net
    #net=net
print '--------net2-------------'
net2 = conv2d(inputs=inp,filters=64,kernel_size=[1,1])
```