# Why tensorflow.contrib.framework.arg_scope not applicable to tf.keras.layers?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am trying to move from tf.contrib.slim to tf.keras packages.
I feel comfortable with arg_scope syntax because it reduces many redundant arguments.

I found the related solution with '[Alternative to arg_scope when using tf.layers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48173368/alternative-to-arg-scope-when-using-tf-layers)'

However, for keras layers it is not applicable and raises following error.

```
from tensorflow.contrib.framework import arg_scope
with arg_scope([tf.keras.layers.Conv2D], padding='SAME', activation='relu'):
  model = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(kernel_size=[3,3])
```

This experimental code results

> ValueError: ('%s is not decorated with @add_arg_scope', 
>      ('tensorflow.python.keras.layers.convolutional', 'Conv2D'))

I am considering to make a wrapper function for `tf.keras.layers` that is decorated with the `add_arg_scope`, but is it a right way of dealing with layers in tf.keras?,
I am also wondering why keras does not support for arg_scope sugar syntax.